# Eloquent Models Returning Numeric and Associative Keys

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, eloquent

I have been working with Laravel 5 for about two months now and I have never had any issues with the framework. It has by far been one of the easiest frameworks to work with, but today something really weird started happening. It is a fresh install of Laravel 5.3 and in this install, my Eloquent Models are returning string and numeric keys for the same data. Example below:

Model:

```
class MailHeader extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'character_id';
    protected $table = 'mail_header';
    protected $fillable = [
        'character_id','mail_id','mail_subject','mail_sender','mail_sent_date','mail_labels','mail_recipient','mail_read'
    ];

}
```

Call To Retrieve Data:

```
$mail_headers = MailHeader::get();
```

Output:

```
[
        "character_id" => 95923084
        0 => 95923084
        "mail_id" => 363893745
        1 => 363893745
        "mail_subject" => "Re: XR fort office rental fee and market service, quick questions"
        2 => "Re: XR fort office rental fee and market service, quick questions"
        "mail_sender" => 94165960
        3 => 94165960
        "mail_sent_date" => "2017-01-12 18:40:00"
        4 => "2017-01-12 18:40:00"
        "mail_labels" => "{}"
        5 => "{}"
        "mail_recipient" => "{}"
        6 => "{}"
        "mail_read" => 1
        7 => 1
        "created_at" => "2017-02-04 07:51:25"
        8 => "2017-02-04 07:51:25"
        "updated_at" => "2017-02-04 07:51:25"
        9 => "2017-02-04 07:51:25"
      ]
```

I am not sure how to word this but can anybody assist me. I am unable to locate any documentation on what can be causing this.

I can confirm that the fetch mode in `Illuminate\Database\Connection.php` is set to `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

In `config/database.php` there is a section called PDO Fetch Style.

This section declares the Fetch type that PDO should use when querying the DB.

I did not have this declare so it was doing `PDO::FETCH_ALL` resulting in returning the same data twice. Once with a Numeric Key and once with an String Key in the Model.

After declaring this section, the return was a regular array. Answer below.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| PDO Fetch Style
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
| stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
| array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
|
*/

'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
```